# Why Not Reading Simple Character Through File?

Tags: c++, unicode, character

I am reading a character from file '☼' this character is typed in notepad by pressing (ALT+15), now I have to print this character and the value 15(Respective ASCII value of this character) on console. The problem is I am getting a square box character with ASCII value -2. Why not this is property working?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream myFile;
    myFile.open("input.txt");
    char inputA;
    myFile>>inputA;
    cout<<inputA<<endl;
    cout<<(int)inputA;



}
```

Comment: ☼ is not an ASCII character, it's a [unicode character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/263c/index.htm). How the character is represented depends on the file's encoding.

Comment: Yes I have saved the file with the option of unicode character. But still not reading properly.

Comment: Also I am getting different result by saving the file with unicode big endian, unicode, and UTF-10

Answer (score 1):

☼ is a unicode character. There are various different encodings of unicode characters, such as UTF-8, UTF-16, and UTF-32. All encodings, however, require more than one byte to represent the character ☼. In fact, the representations are:

```
UTF-8   0xE2 0x98 0xBC
UTF-16  0x263C
UTF-32  0x0000263C
```

The order of the bytes in UTF-16 and UTF-32 depends on the endianness of the system.

You're trying to read the character into a single `char`. This will only extract a single byte of the character. I don't know where your -2 has come from, but when I try it on a UTF-8 encoded ☼, I get the value -30. This is because a signed `char` with representation `0xE2` is -30.

How you read the character properly, depends on the encoding too. For UTF-8, you will need to read an array of 3 `char` just for that character. For UTF-16, you can use `char16_t` to read a character. For UTF-32, there's `char32_t`.